# Getting latest node to display as front page

Tags: 6, nodes

I have what seems like a simple question about something it seems like many Drupal users would want to do, yet I cannot seem to find a good answer. I want my latest node (preferably of a single content type) to show as the front page. If I add a node, I want it to automatically become the front page. I don't want the front page to list nodes, etc. I found the "Top Node" module, which offers a view called "Single Node", which seems to do exactly what I want, but it has some problems (notably that it breaks the <front> alias used in setting block displays). There must be some way to do something that seems to be so common without an additional module, right?

I am aware that I could create a view that pulls the content from my latest node and creates a new page for it, but that seems like overkill, since the node already exists. Also, some of my node is being created programatically, and I cannot get those parts of the full node using a view.

How can I do this? Is there no built-in way?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I described exactly what I wanted to do with details, why I wanted to do it, and exactly what I tried. I have spent hours on Google and Drupal.org, and I cannot find any answers. This is not as simple as setting the frontpage url in site information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Views and attach a PAGE format. Then for display format: "full content". Its not overkill since your page would be cached anyways. But if your really not keen on using views, your best bet is to create a new tpl file for your theme and gear it towards the frontpage via: node--front.tpl.php (not sure if it was like that, but google it) Then return the latest node filtered by content type.

Comment: Ah, yes, sweet [insert Holy Figure here]. That is what I was looking for!